# Plutus Contracts Delegation

Tags: plutus, decentralized-applications, plutus-pioneer-program

Is there or will there be such a thing where delegators can stake to a smart contract itself, rather than a pool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, as the smart contract cannot produce blocks.

However, funds within a smart contact can be delegated to a pool.